# Why can't delete row in Eureka demo?

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

)

I try learn something from Eureka Demo, but when I enter Eureka Demo App :

Multivalued Sections -> select any row (e.g:Multivalued Only Delete):

[image: how can I delete any row???]

I can't tap left delete button to delete any row,why?

and source code is here:

```
class MultivaluedOnlyDeleteController: FormViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!

  override func rowsHaveBeenRemoved(_ rows: [BaseRow], at indexes: [IndexPath]) {
      print("delete row")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      tableView.isEditing = false
      let nameList = ["family", "male", "female", "client"]

      let section = MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: .Delete, footer: "you can swipe to delete when table.isEditing = false (Not Editing)")


      for tag in nameList {
          section <<< TextRow {
                          $0.placeholder = "Tag Name"
                          $0.value = tag
                      }
      }


      let section2 =  MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: .Delete, footer: "")
      for _ in 1..<4 {
          section2 <<< PickerInlineRow<String> {
                          $0.title = "Tap to select"
                          $0.value = "client"
                          $0.options = nameList
                       }
      }

      editButton.title = tableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
      editButton.target = self
      editButton.action = #selector(editPressed(sender:))

      form    +++

              section

              +++

              section2
  }

  @objc func editPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
      tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
      editButton.title = tableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"

  }
}
```

I don't know If I miss something???

thanks

Comment: its a bug in the demo implementation of that ViewController I see that you had open an issue in eureka repo

Comment: I had opened a pull request fixing this issue @hopy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in the demo is that they have missing add actions in the cell

**CurrentCode Code**

```
    for tag in nameList {
        section <<< TextRow {
                        $0.placeholder = "Tag Name"
                        $0.value = tag

                    }
    }
```

**Fixed Code**

```
    for tag in nameList {
        section <<< TextRow {
                        $0.placeholder = "Tag Name"
                        $0.value = tag

                        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, row, completionHandler) in
                            print("Delete")
                            completionHandler?(true)
                        }

                        $0.trailingSwipe.actions = [deleteAction]
                    }
    }
```

fixed issue demo code in gihub, on my fork https://github.com/rmelian2014/Eureka

Comment: thanks! but deleteAction block seem like never been called? beacuse I write some code under code print("Delete"),make breakpoint on it. when I remove specified row and nothing happened... is it only a stub???

Comment: I mean is that if I want write some another codes in deleteAction(SwipeAction),or add one more action to trailingSwipe.actions,  How can I make sure those actions been called??? thanks

Comment: oh! I also notice that when I change code to MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: **.None**,...) , I can't swipe row anyway! why is that? How can I fix that? (because in demo,row in single section at SwipeActionsController can swipe anyway.) thanks. ;) @ReinierMelian

Comment: @hopy can you clone the demo from my fork and test it?

Comment: Man you saved my life" Tks so much